# Magento - How to add column to product list in admin create new shipping?

Tags: xml, magento, adminhtml

I'm currently trying to add a new column to a product order, when you create a new shipment (the adminhtml/blocks/sales/order/shipment/create area) and have been beating my head against for a while, with various different guides. I've tried to change the item.phtml and form.phtml with very little success.

I was able to change the form block itself (form.php), but that's little help with the deeper core of the product listing. I'd like each product to have a column for its manufacturer attribute, but I'd be happy with just a column showing up where it's supposed to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
You can refer below xml there are two path block and template either my creating new files or editing same you can get result


app\design\adminhtml\default\default\layout\sales.xml
<block type="adminhtml/sales_order_view_items" name="order_items" template="sales/order/view/items.phtml">
    <action method="addItemRender"><type>default</type><block>adminhtml/sales_order_view_items_renderer_default</block><template>sales/order/view/items/renderer/default.phtml</template></action>
    <action method="addColumnRender"><column>qty</column><block>adminhtml/sales_items_column_qty</block><template>sales/items/column/qty.phtml</template></action>
    <action method="addColumnRender"><column>name</column><block>adminhtml/sales_items_column_name</block><template>sales/items/column/name.phtml</template></action>
    <action method="addColumnRender"><column>name</column><block>adminhtml/sales_items_column_name_grouped</block><template>sales/items/column/name.phtml</template><type>grouped</type></action>
    <block type="core/text_list" name="order_item_extra_info" />
</block>
```

Comment: I've attempted to edit both form.phtml and items.phtml, and neither have had any effect. Could you possibly explain a bit more in what way they should be altered?

Comment: Thanks for your help! I actually found them within the .phtml files associated with those methods, and the controller, well, in the controllers. For anyone else hoping to do what I am, here's the locations:

Column Content: 
  adminhtml/default/default/template/sales/order/shipment/create/items/renderer/default.phtml

Column Headings:    

adminhtml/default/default/template/sales/order/shipment/create/items.phtml

Controller:    
Adminhtml/controllers/Sales/Order/ShipmentController.php